# How to print 2d lists in python like a C table

Tags: python, list, printing

i have a 2 lists and i want to make a 2d list but i want to be printed like a 2d table (like in C) and not in one row! My code is like:

```
c = []
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        c.append(a[i]-a[j])
print c
```

this is printed in a row

Comment: Please tell us exactly how the output is supposed to look like for an example list.

Comment: You can print `c` any way you want. Just write code (nested `for` loops?) that do it the way you want — in other words, don't just do a `print c` and expect it to be formatted the way you want.

Comment: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]            i cant post exactly,dont know why...i want for          example every five "0" to change line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Python 2 based on your code sample:

```
c = []
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        c.append(a[i] - a[j])
        print c[-1],
    print
```

Comment: exactly what i needed!!!! thank you!!! but what is the difference between print c[-1], and print c??

Comment: @ThanosSmar, the `print c[-1],` just prints the last item you added to the array `c`.  If you don't need to collect these items into `c` since you're just printing them, you can just print `a[i] - a[j]`.  The trailing comma on this print statement supresses the newline.  The standalone `print` generates a newline.

Comment: Wow...i'm new here...what do you mean exactly?